# Tesseract gives wrong results when extracting data from table

Tags: c#, tesseract

I want to extract text from a table using Tesseract.
The text is extracted okay, but I also get some weird output and I don't know where it is coming from. The weird output begins from the 9th column onwards.
The image has 300dpi as Tesseract developers suggested and I am using the wrapper for C# for Tesseract 3.04. I also tried to remove the lines but that did not help.

What could I do the enhance the image so that I can get the correct results?
For reference, here is the image and the output.

Original image: [image]

Here is part of the output that shows the wrong results: [image]

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Had similar issues with Tesseract. If you know the area of the column you can use `engine.Process(Bitmap image, Tesseract.Rect region, PageSegMode? pageSegMode = null)`. (define your rect like this: `var rect = new Tesseract.Rect(1205,259, 28,20);`) This will limit your OCR to just that zone. It may not give you the correct result, but it gives you something to compare.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have changed the page segment mode into SingleBlock and it seems to work fine.